# How do I identify partial duplicates in an excel list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a list of over 1000 company names, however some are duplicated but they aren't exact duplicates (ie: Nintendo, Nintendo Inc, Nintendo Video games, etc), is there a way to identify the duplicates so that I can group them together?

I was using the below code but it's not picking up some of them and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub TestForDups()

Dim LLoop As Integer
Dim LTestLoop As Integer
Dim LClearRange As String
Dim Lrows As Integer
Dim LRange As String
Dim LChangedValue As String
Dim LTestValue As String

'Test first 2000 rows in spreadsheet for uniqueness
Lrows = 2000
LLoop = 2

'Clear all flags
LClearRange = "A2:A" & Lrows
Range(LClearRange).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

'Check first 2000 rows in spreadsheet
While LLoop <= Lrows
  LChangedValue = "A" & CStr(LLoop)

  If Len(Range(LChangedValue).Value) > 0 Then
     'Test each value for uniqueness
     LTestLoop = 2
     While LTestLoop <= Lrows
        If LLoop <> LTestLoop Then
           LTestValue = "A" & CStr(LTestLoop)
           'Value has been duplicated in another cell
           If InStr(Range(LTestValue).Value, Range(LChangedValue).Value) > 0 Then
              'Set the background color to red
              Range(LChangedValue).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
              Range(LTestValue).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

           End If

        End If

        LTestLoop = LTestLoop + 1

     Wend

  End If

  LLoop = LLoop + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: look into Fuzzy Lookups. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are fuzzy lookup add-ins which can be hooked into Excel, as @Scott Craner mentions.

Download the Fuzzy Lookup plugin from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Tutorial for setting up and using fuzzy lookups in Excel: http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/431-tip-fuzzy-lookups-in-excel

Video tutorial showing how to use the tool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v-qxcjZbyo

There is some pretty complex matching algorithm stuff going on in the plugin, so it's not surprising that your script doesn't quite implement what you wanted perfectly with that much code. Good on you for trying though!